# displaying output from a data frame

Tags: r

I have a database of baseball batters and have developed the following random forest model to predict their potential success in getting into the baseball Hall of Fame (just based on their batting success, but also adding things like whether they were implicated in steroids).

```
rf <- randomForest(HOF ~ runs + rbi + bb + hits + so + doubles + BA + 
hr + stolen_base + triples + Playing_Era + Banned + Steroids, data = batters,
na.action=na.exclude, importance = TRUE)
```

I would like to develop code that extracts the names of the players that meet the conditions of the model.

The code that I have, for prediction and output is as follows:

```
p=predict(rf, na.action="na.exclude")
length(p)
length(batters$HOF)
t=table(p, batters$HOF)
t

x=sum(table(predict(rf, na.action="na.exclude"), batters$HOF))

lname=vector()
for (i in 1:10084){
  if (batters$HOF[i]=="No" & as.character(p[i])=="Yes")
    lname[i]=batters$lastname[i] & fname[i]=batters$firstname[i]
  else {
    break
  }
}

z=data.frame(batters$lastname, batters$firstname, batters$HOF,p)

View(z[z[,4]=="Yes" & z[,3]=="No",])

z[z]
table(z)
lname
```

I would like the last name and, ideally, the first name of the batter (in case there are two people with the same last name) to be listed.  The following line in the code gets me to the data frame extraction where I can see the results and manually input the names in my report.

```
View(z[z[,4]=="Yes" & z[,3]=="No",])
```

However, I'm hoping to have the results displayed in R without having me retype them.  Instead, when I get to the code z[z], I get the following error message:

`Error in [.default(z, z) : invalid subscript type 'list'`

Then, without it, the table and the last name list don't show up either.

Any help you can provide to help me list the last names in the R output without having me retype them from the table I get from the View(z[z[,4]=="Yes" & z[,3]=="No",]) line is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you are trying `z[z]`?

Comment: As to why z[z], my guess is I'm doing it wrong, but figured that z[z] would return the name that is listed in the data frame z.  I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: I think I figured it out, and I feel kind of dumb that it was as straight-forward.  Thank you Heikki for the nudge.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't elegant, but was able to solve by just assigning a couple new objects.

```
z1 <- (z[z[,4]=="Yes" & z[,3]=="No",])
z_complete <- z1[complete.cases(z1), ]
z_final <- with(z_complete, z_complete[order(batters.lastname, batters.firstname, batters.HOF, p),])
z_final
```

If someone has something that looks a little nicer without creating the two new objects, I'd appreciate the pointer.

Thanks again, Heikki!